# SQL Loader ctl file - how to skip columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader, ctl

Let's say in my database 4 columns:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
```

My data file is CSV file (comma delimited, length of column is unknown):

```
xxx,yyy,zzz,000  
a,bb,ccccc,ddddddd  
1,2,3,4
```

The CTL will be:

```
LOAD DATA
INTO TABLE "TABLE" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4     
)
```

I want to skip Column3, how can I do that? I know about `FILLER` but it doesn't work for old oracle versions.

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: different versions including < 8

Answer (score 3):

If that's an option just drop the third column with a shell tool. That's *just works*.

E.g. with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print $1 FS $2 FS $4 }' INFILE > TMPOUTFILE
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]\+,[^,]\+,\)[^,]\+,/\1/' INFILE > TMPOUTFILE
```

(and you can pick several other tools (e.g. `cut`...)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if this is supported in early versions, but in later ones you can user an [SQL operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10701/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008150):

```
LOAD DATA
INTO TABLE "TABLE" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3 "decode(:Column3,null,null,null)",
    Column4
)
```

... which will set `Column3` to null whether it has a value in the data file or not.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use an intermediate or load table, like so:

```
LOAD DATA
INTO TABLE "LOADTABLE" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4     
)
```

and then call a stored proc afterwards that handles the population of your main table, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pop_table
IS
   CURSOR cur_load_table
   IS
              SELECT column1
                   , column2
                   , column4
                FROM loadtable;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN cur_load_table
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO table( column1
                       , column2
                       , column4 )
      VALUES ( rec.column1
             , rec.column2
             , rec.column4 );
   END LOOP;
END pop_table;
```